# Swift 1.2 lowercaseString crashes with enumerateSubstringInRange

Tags: ios, swift

Just converted my code to Swift 1.2. I'm getting a BAD_EXEC_ACCESS with the below code:

```
var wordsBeingTyped = NSString()
var lastWord = String()

wordsBeingTyped = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput // Gets the string being typed
let range = NSMakeRange(0, (wordsBeingTyped).length)
wordsBeingTyped.enumerateSubstringsInRange(range, options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
            lastWord = substring // The last word in the string wordsBeingTyped
        }

let lastWordLowercase = lastWord.lowercaseString
```

The crash is happening on the last line. For testing purposes I changed that line to:

```
let lastWordLowercase = wordsBeingTyped.lowercaseString
```

And it works just fine. The strange thing is it only crashes when I'm typing the first word in a string. After a space character there is no crashing.

**Update:** The work around I came up with is to make a new let to convert wordsBeingTyped to lowercase before using enumerateSubstringsInRange. So:

```
let lowercaseWordsBeingTyped = wordsBeingTyped.lowercaseString

// ..enumerate string to get last word typed

let lastWordLowercase = lastWord
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: use var  instead of let also check the length of wordsBeingTyped if it is more than 1

Comment: @VikramKThakor I have already tried var. Didn't help. I'll try the other thing.

Comment: Second suggestion doesn't work either. I can even set a breakpoint and in the console type po lastWord.lowercaseString and it will print the correct string in lower case.

Comment: Does *proxy.documentContextBeforeInput* return *NSString* or *NSString?*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Xcode 6.3 beta 1. [It's fixed in Xcode 6.3 beta 2](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_2/Xcode_6.3_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf).

Comment: "Fixed a use after free crash in lowercaseString and uppercaseString. (19801253)"