# Swift 1.2 crashes with .lowercaseString

Tags: ios, xcode6, swift

I have this relatively simple method for filtering a tableView's datasource objects.

```
func filterCategoriesWithQuery(query: String) {

    placeCategoriesTableViewDataSource.filteredCategories
        = placeCategoriesTableViewDataSource.placeCategories.filter({ (category: JSON) -> Bool in

        let categoryName = (category["name"].stringValue).lowercaseString
        if categoryName.hasPrefix(query.lowercaseString)  {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }

    })

    genericTableView.reloadData()
```

This worked perfectly well prior to updating to Swift-1.2/Xcode-6.3b but now it always crashes when `lowercaseString` is utilised. It seems there's a bug with the `lowercaseString` method?

With `NSZombieEnabled` or breaking at `malloc_free_break` I can see that it crashes with `[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance`

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Any workarounds?

Comment: Looks like query is becoming out of scope. To start debugging this, I suggest making a temporary string var inside your func that takes query. Use this in your block.

Comment: @Daniel It doesn't seem getting out of scope. Not using `lowecaseString` whatsoever, works properly. If there's either one of the two calls, it crashes.

Comment: Same problem different situation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28471161/3804019

Comment: @rintaro I can't see how I can use the same workaround here

Comment: Try splitting `category["name"].stringValue).lowercaseString` into multiple statements.

Comment: @David nop, still crashing.

Comment: I am starting to believe this is a bug related to `lowercaseString` being used in the context of a closure... Don't have any other reasonable explanation.

Comment: There may be a bug somewhere earlier in your code that is only showing up at this point because you have in some way caused the double release of an object, or some other heap corruption. The fact that it happens with Swift 1.2/6.3b and not with an earlier version is *not* necessarily an indication that it's a bug in Swift - it might be a bug in Swift, but I'd strongly suspect a bug in your code first that simply did not surface previously.

Comment: Someone on freenode confirmed that this is a known issue with 1.2... I really can't see any other way for this happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the first beta of Swift 1.2.
On the Apple Developer Forums, Chris Lattner mentioned [a similar bug with uppercaseString](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1102454#1102454) that should be fixed in the next beta.

Until then, as a workaround, you can try to change the Swift compiler optimization to none in the build settings of your project. This helped me to get around a similar issue I had with an Array.

Comment: And, according to the release notes for [Xcode 6.3 beta 2](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_2/Xcode_6.3_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf), that fix has now arrived.